# Vue - Why are some images getting a hash in production and others not?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have this CSS for some of my icons:

```
ul.grid-list li.input-grid-box input.input.consumption {
    background: url(../img/icons/icon-consumption.png) no-repeat scroll 3px 14px;
    background-size: 21px;
}
ul.grid-list li.input-grid-box input.input.workforce {
    background: url(../img/icons/icon-workforce.png) no-repeat scroll 3px 11px;
    background-size: 14px;
}
ul.grid-list li.input-grid-box input.input.time {
    background: url(../img/icons/icon-time.png) no-repeat scroll 3px 10px;
    background-size: 16px;
}
ul.grid-list li.input-grid-box input.input.rooms {
    background: url(../img/icons/icon-rooms.png) no-repeat scroll 3px 7px;
    background-size: 20px;
}
```

Every time I build my project and look inside `dist/assets/img` there is only one icon (icon-rooms) that has a hash (`icon-rooms.575a049f.png`) while all the others are just inside /icons/ folder without such a hash. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*By default, generated static assets contains hashes in their filenames for better caching control.*

[See official vue.js documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#filenamehashing)

You can disable this though.

Comment: I see. But the question is: why is it only just one icon that has the hashing and not all of them if they are used the same way?

Comment: Frankly, I don't have an answer for that question. But I suppose that has to do with the image-size and some image-metadata.
At building your static project, Vue will check if caching will improve speed for each file and only rename them if so.